# Not able to start SonarCube server in MacOSx

Tags: java, sonarqube

Running the latest version of sonarcube 7.1.2 and getting the following error.:

**Command executed: sudo ./sonar.sh**

```
Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.07.01 18:36:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or 
creating temp directory /Users/aneeshgoel/Downloads/sonarqube-7.2.1/temp

2018.07.01 18:36:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch 
listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.07.01 18:36:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch 
process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from 
[/Users/aneeshgoel/Downloads/sonarqube-7.2.1/elasticsearch]: 
/Users/aneeshgoel/Downloads/sonarqube- 
7.2.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch - 
Epath.conf=/Users/aneeshgoel/Downloads/sonarqube-7.2.1/temp/conf/es

2018.07.01 18:36:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for 
Elasticsearch to be up and running

2018.07.01 18:36:10 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.07.01 18:36:10 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin 
[org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]

2018.07.01 18:36:16 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process 
exited with exit value [es]: 1

2018.07.01 18:36:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is 
stopped
2018.07.01 18:36:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is 
stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Then I tried with non sudo user. **Command ./sonar.sh**

Error got is :

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.07.01 18:18:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /Users/aneeshgoel/Downloads/sonarqube-7.2.1/temp

WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Users/aneeshgoel/Downloads/sonarqube-7.2.1/temp/conf/es/elasticsearch.yml
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Users/aneeshgoel/Downloads/sonarqube-7.2.1/temp/conf/es/elasticsearch.yml
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
at org.sonar.process.FileUtils2$DeleteRecursivelyFileVisitor.visitFile(FileUtils2.java:170)
```

I have tried giving write access also to the directory , but still no luck. Please can someone help in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube installation guide, unfortunately, doesn’t say a thing about configuring user for the analysis server. People that are installing it can later forget about it, leaving SonarQube running with root rights for a while.

It is, however pretty simple and straightforward. Prepare sonar system user and change installation directory rights:

You have to run the sonar in the context of `sonar` user. To create a user called sonar, follow these steps:

> groupadd sonar useradd -c "Sonar System User" -d /opt/sonarqube -g
>   sonar -s /bin/bash sonar chown -R sonar:sonar /opt/sonarqube

Then edit the file present here:

> /opt/sonarqube/bin/sonar.sh

Find the line which reads **RUN_AS_USER=sonar** which will be commented, and then change as sonar and try to run the app now.